# rename file while uploading with php

Tags: php

I have a php script which uploads files:

```
for($index = 0;$index < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $index++){
        
    // File name
    $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$index];
            
    // File path
    $path = '../pdf/'.$filename;
                
    // Upload file
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$index],$path)){
        // ERROR
        exit;
    }
```

This works fine!
But I would like to modify the filename while uploading:

For example:
I uploading a "upload.pdf" file.
But I would like to get the name "upload_2021.pdf"

How can I realize it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP file rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635831/php-file-rename)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not change `$path`  to the expected filename?

Comment: I tried this: `$path = '../pdf/'.$filename.'_2021';` But the result will be upload.pdf_2021. Thats not correct

Comment: You really need to be a little more precise with the criteria needed for the renaming process. Presumably `2021` is the year appended to the file's basename but this clearly has scope for name conflicts. `"I found a solution !!"` is part of a solution but not a whole solution - it merely splits the file name and extension. I'm not sure the duplicate applies completely but this does need more effort

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution !!

```
$path = '../pdf/'.$filename;
$extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$name = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the only thing you need to do is change the $path variable.

Bare in mind, that what you are showing here is not a safe and secure upload script. You are not doing any file and mime-type validation what so ever. There is nothing preventing your users from uploading harmful files. Together with not checking for duplicate files and some other edge cases, think twice before putting this into production.

```
for($index = 0;$index < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $index++){
    // File name
    $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$index];

    $parts = explode(".", $filename);
    $year = date("Y");
    // File path
    $path = '../pdf/'.$parts[0] . '_' $year . '.' . $parts[count($parts)-1];
            
    // Upload file
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$index],$path)){
        // ERROR
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**a short example:**

```php
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
```

Comment: Won't work for all files, e.g. `.htaccess`, `.hiddenfile`, `macfiles`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this generate a filename like `upload_2021.pdf` in the folder `pdf`?